# g++: Static linking not working

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, g++

I'm trying to link the standard library in my project statically. I've tried several variations of static link options from various threads on SO and other sites (http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/), but none of them have yielded the desired results.

Here's my current flag setup:

```
g++ -Wall -g -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Iinclude -std=c++11
```

I've also tried:

```
g++ -Wall -g -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -std=c++11
```

With either of these variations, the output of `ldd` still is:

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xb77b1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x4e085000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4daf0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 -> /lib/libgcc_s.s0.1 (0x4dd1f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4d90a000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x4d8e7000)
```

Running `file` also tells me that it's a dynamically linked binary. I've tried this on multiple distros, including Fedora 18, Ubuntu 12.04, and CentOS, but to no avail.

Comment: How are you compiling? Via make? Manually with g++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++ -Wall -g -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -std=c++0x hello.cpp
```

with this output from ldd

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffef928000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe12439000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe12822000)
```

does the job under my Ubuntu 12.04, also I doubt that you are using the gcc/g++ version supported under Ubuntu 12.04 because it's g++ 4.6 and g++ 4.6 doesn't offer the `-std=c++11` flag.

```
g++ -std=c++0x -static hello.cpp
```

this also works as expected compiling everything into a single static object.

the source of my `hello.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  [](void){std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}();
  return(0);
}
```

I think that you are playing with different compilers or with compilers that are not supported by your platform, document yourself about your compiler version, this flags work, the problem is probably your installation or the settings in your compiler.

Comment: Hm, curious. I'm using gcc 4.7.2, but I can't find any resources on possible bugs involving static linking.

Comment: @JohnRuffer it can also simply be a problem about your settings or your library, it's not necessarily a bug. try to make a more verbose compilation adding the `-v` flag, or `-Wl,-v` just for the linker, to your `g++` and start with a minimal and simple set of flags.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I walked through my makefile; it was indeed a configuration error. I inadvertently omitted the flags in on of my targets. Silly me. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to link -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ with others static libraries: protobuf, pthread, rt and every time I had a different problem.

The solution I found was to use an external tool [Ermine](http://magicermine.com/index.html) and solves all my problems. based on: [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/)